# How to apply a random font to a textbox by scripting InDesign?

Tags: fonts, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I want to choose a random font from my installed fonts and apply it to a text box. I am using basil.js to facilitate coding.

I don't want to write a list of all available fonts by myself, like this:

```
var font = [];
font[0] = "Times New Roman";
font[1] = "Myriad Pro";
font[2] = "Impact";
b.textFont( font[Math.floor(Math.random()*font.length)] );
```

(this idea is from: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/325180)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your basil.js play nice along with ID's native Extendscript? If so, you can use this:

```
var allFonts = app.fonts.everyItem().getElements();
b.textFont( allFonts[Math.floor(Math.random()*allFonts.length)] );
```

The first line accesses the *live* app.fonts object in InDesign, and since this is slow I prefer to use the `everyItem().getElements()` trick to 'convert' it to a static array first. Typically you would do this only once, near the start of your script.

Comment: Yes, Extendscript and basil.js play nice. Thus, this works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Jongware's answer ... there is now also an example which does exactly that: https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/blob/master/examples/typography/RandomFonts.jsx

```
#includepath "~/Documents/;%USERPROFILE%Documents";
#include "basiljs/bundle/basil.js";

function draw() {
  var textFramesCount = 20;
  var fonts = app.fonts;

  for (var i=0; i < textFramesCount; i++) {
    var posX = b.random(0,600);
    var posY = b.random(0,850);
    var randomFontSize = b.round(b.random(2,20));
    var randomIndex = b.floor( b.random(app.fonts.length) );
    var fontName = fonts[randomIndex].fullName;
    b.println(fontName);

    b.textSize( randomFontSize );
    b.textFont( fonts[randomIndex] );
    var textFrame = b.text(fontName+" "+randomFontSize, posX,posY, 300,20);
  };
}

b.go();
```